# How to write this code in one or two line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I want to write this code in one line or max two lines...

Input : https://youtu.be/hNUtnu14wzg

**required output : hNUtnu14wzg**

input : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=/hNUtnu14wzg

required output : **hNUtnu14wzg**

```
x=str(input())[::-1]
videoID=[]
for i in x:
    if i=="/" or i=="=":
        break
    else:
        videoID.append(i)
        
print(''.join(videoID)[::-1])
```

Comment: I'm down voting this because: Community guidelines state that asking for compressed code without any decent reason isnt allowed.

Comment: Have you considered using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: `input.split(r'/')[-1]`

Comment: @YossiLevi You don't need a raw string here.

Comment: sorry, didn't understand what you meant

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Community guidelines state that asking for compressed code without any decent reason isn't allowed.

Comment: @YossiLevi You defined a raw string with `r'/'`. Just `'/' ` would be enough.

Comment: It just an habit, to ignore escape characters. good practice in my opinion which adopted I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
videoID = [i for i in x if i != "/" and i != "="]
```

But for the youtube urls you provided, you can do this:

```
url = 'https://youtu.be/hNUtnu14wzg'
video_id = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] # video_id = 'hNUtnu14wzg'

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNUtnu14wzg'
video_id = url.rsplit('/watch?v=', 1)[-1] # video_id = 'hNUtnu14wzg'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer bro.... how to write if else statement in one line?

Comment: `value = "foo" if x == 1 else "bar"`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(m_in1.split(r'/')[-1] if "/" in m_in else m_in)
```

will print the substring follows the last apperance of `/` and the whole string if the character not exist.

**example without slash**

```
m_in1 = "something without any slash"
print(m_in1.split(r'/')[-1] if "/" in m_in1 else m_in1)
```

output:

```
something without any slash
```

**example with slash**

```
m_in2 = " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=/hNUtnu14wzg"
print(m_in2.split(r'/')[-1] if "/" in m_in2 else m_in2)
```

output:

```
hNUtnu14wzg
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer bro... grateful of you!